# Answer deleted, without notice, no chance to improve etc.?

Tags: support, specific-answer, deleted-answers

**EDIT: I edited my answer, could it please be undeleted?**

I posted an answer to the question
[*How to convince my parents I’m happy with my social life?*](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/8241/345) and it seems the answer was deleted.

I received an email notifying me that there were comments, but my inbox doesn’t show any. Plus there’s no notification or anything letting me know what happened to my answer.

I’m quite new on interpersonal skills, but not on SE in general. What I always appreciated on SE was the fact that questions and answers could be shaped and improved by other users’ feedback to build a community of valuable knowledge over time.

Believe me, if I didn’t care about that fundamental feature on SE and at the same time the issue the OP presented in his question, I wouldn’t have spent time and thought to add to the existing answers.

- So, what happened to my answer and how did that happen?
- How can I get to read comments to my post and reflect those on the quality of my post and shape it accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was deleted by three votes from the community. [This MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work/) explains how comments on deleted posts work, so you probably had a mismatch because there were no mod comments on your answer. For whatever reason StackExchange just doesn't notify you when your posts are deleted. (There have been multiple feature requests to this end over on MSE but it's still not a thing: [Send authors an inbox message if their question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed), [Notice of Deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion), etc.)

Anyhow, you can look at your recently deleted answers using this link: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/9437

I think you should be able to see the comments, but just in case, here they are:

> How does this answer the question? – Em C yesterday
>
> Good points, but it lacks answering what OP is asking though... Do you mind adding an explanation and improve, please? – OldPadawan yesterday
>
> My partner would be offended if you suggested she was pushing our son to find a partner. She would be incandescent with fury if you suggested she was pushing him to marry or have children. – Martin Bonner yesterday
>
> ... and we would both be entirely comfortable if the partner turned out to be a guy. (None of them have been yet.) – Martin Bonner yesterday

So, I flagged it as NAA (Not An Answer) because the question is "How can I convince my parents I am happy with my social life?", not "Why does my mother nag me about my social life?". Your answer talks about how moms always want XYZ for their kids, but doesn't provide any actual advice to the OP on what they can do.

If the sentence about "Young adults usually respond by moving out" was meant to be your advice for this specific situation, you should make that more clear and expand on why that is the best solution for the OP.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and directing me. I edited my post and ask you and others to vote to undelete it.

Comment: @michi it's undeleted now. Good edit!